# Подключение к удалённому Mysql серверу с помощью Python

Tags: python, mysql, linux, ssh, ip

Подключение через консоль к серверу:

```
$ ssh user@host
password:
```

и подключение к базе

```
$ mysql -ucc70818_1 -p
Enter password:
```

отрабатывает отлично. Потребовалось подключиться через python. Вот код:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    'vh394.timeweb.ru',
    ssh_username='user',
    ssh_password='password',
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
)

server.start()

connector = pymysql.connect(
    host="37.76.166.225", # мой ip (так же пробовал через 127.0.0.1, но через localhost
    # не хочет подключаться к серверу)
    port=server.local_bind_port,
    user="user",
    password="db_password",
    database="db_name",
)
server.stop()
```

При запуске получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kostya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 613, in connect
    sock = socket.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kostya/PycharmProjects/my_project_/mysql_/mysql_class.py", line 89, in <module>
    connector = pymysql.connect(
  File "/home/kostya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/home/kostya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 664, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '37.76.166.225' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

Но почему так, я не понимаю. Буду рад любой помощи.
Так как это больше учебный процесс, могу скинуть пароли от сервера.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `мой ip`, вот тут нужно проверить. 1) ip статичный или динамичный? 2) мб у вас есть роутер, в котором нужно указать проброс портов?

Comment: Попробуйте ещё раз 127.0.0.1 и покажите текст ошибки именно при использовании 127.0.0.1

Comment: @gil9red, 1) ip динамический, но перед тем как запускать, я проверил ip на https://2ip.ru/. Из-за этого проблем не могло возникнуть (хотя, возможно я чего-то не понимаю). 2) да, роутер имеется, пока еще не пробовал, как попробую, отпишу. СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!!!

Comment: @andreymal, ошибка:
`
ERROR   | Secsh channel 0 open FAILED: open failed: Administratively prohibited
ERROR   | Could not establish connection from local ('127.0.0.1', 33457) to remote ('127.0.0.1', 3306) side of the tunnel: open new channel ssh error: ChannelException(1, 'Administratively prohibited')
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
`

Comment: Ошибка намекает на то, что проброс порта запрещён администратором сервера

Comment: @andreymal, а не знаете как разрешить проброс? и я не понимаю, чем подключение через консоль отличается от подключения через python. почему через python нельзя просто указать так же user@host и потом password(

Comment: Если администратор сервера не хочет, чтобы вы подключались к mysql за пределами сервера, то ничего вы с этим не сделаете